Convergence in $L^1$ under precise hypothesis
I must prove the following result.
Let $\{f_n\}\subseteq L^1(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$, $f\in L^1$ such that
$(i)$ $f_n\to f\quad\text{a.e. in}\; X$
$(ii)$ $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{X} |f_n|\;d\mu=\int_X |f|\;d\mu$.
Then $$\int_X |f_n-f|\to 0\;\text{for}\; n\to\infty\tag1$$
Proof.
Define $\phi_n=||f_n|-|f|-|f_n-f||$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then we have that $\phi_n\to 0$ a.e. in $X$ in fact result that
$0\le \phi_n= ||f_n|-|f|-|f_n-f||\le ||f_n|-|f||+|f_n-f|\le 2 |f_n-f|\to 0$
for $(i)$.
It's simple to see that $\phi_n\le 2|f|\in L^1.$ Then for the DCT we have that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X \phi_n\;d\mu=\int_X ||f_n|-|f|-|f_n-f||\;d\mu=0\tag2$$
My problem is to deduce $(1)$ from $(2)$.
I write as I did
$$ \int_X |f_n-f|\;d\mu =  \int_X \left(|f_n-f|-|f_n|+|f|\right)\;d\mu+\int_X (|f_n|-|f|)\;d\mu \\
\le \int_X \left | |f_n-f|-|f_n|+|f|\right|\;d\mu+\int_X(|f_n|-|f|)\;d\mu\\= \int_X ||f_n|-|f|-|f_n-f||\;d\mu+\int_X (|f_n|-|f|)\;d\mu\to 0$$
for $(ii)$ and $(2)$.
The first integral converges to $0$ for $(2)$ and the last integral converges to $0$ for $(ii)$.
It's correct?

You don't need the outer pair of modulus signs in the first of the last three steps. You can conclude without using the integral inequality. This result is known as Scheffé's lemma, by the way.

@legionwhaleThanks. I removed the absolute value you said, but I still can't conclude.

The convergence of the second term in that line is now simply one of the hypotheses of the proof.

@legionwhaleYes, in fact I had not yet used hypothesis $(ii)$, but I cannot understand why hypothesis $(ii)$ implies the convergence of that integral.

By linearity of the integral, $\int_X (|f_n| -|f|) = \int_X |f_n| - \int_X |f|$. (A little care must be taken when splitting the integral in this way that none of the terms are infinite, but this is fine here.)

@legionwhaleBut in the second integral there is a modulus.

There isn't; that was a remnant of the redundant modulus signs you added at first. The first of the last three lines is now correct, but the last two are not needed since you can apply (ii) directly from the first line.

@legionwhale Now I've corrected it. Could you check if everything is okay now?

Yes, the proof is correct. The modulus signs inside the first integral are not needed either, technically; the DCT applies without the modulus also. But that's not an issue.

@legionwhaleSorry if I bother you again. The proof that $\phi_n\to 0$ a.e. it is correct?

No problem. Yes, it's fine.
